# how to set direction for list of values 'LOV' in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, lov

how can I change direction of LOV using set_item_property ?
I want to change the direction based on a parameter value , if set_item_property is not available do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: What does "direction" mean in this context? I've never heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

use an 'ORDER BY' clause at the end of the query. using either ASC for ascending data 'ABCD' or DESC for descending order 'ZYX' e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
ORDER BY parameter ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
ORDER BY parameter DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ordering of the listed values in ascending or descending manner by the word *direction*, you can manage it through use of **Set_Lov_Property**.

You should be calling the existing `LOV` from a text field(call `tf1`).

Add a check box item (call `cb1`) next to `tf1`.

Forms creates a `Record Group` as `LOV` being created with the same name as default(call `'mylov01'`). Assume this `Record Group` has a select statement having `order by col0 asc` clause.

Manually create an extra `Record Group` with name `mylov01_desc` having `order by col0 desc` clause.

Add a `KEY-CLRBLK` trigger to that field with the code

```
declare
    v_lov varchar2(50) := 'mylov01'; 
    v_grn varchar2(50);     
begin   
    if    Checkbox_Checked('cb1') then
        v_grn := v_lov||'_desc';
    else    
        v_grn := v_lov; 
    end if; 

    Set_Lov_Property( v_lov, group_name, v_grn );   
    list_values;
end;
```

Invoke the `LOV` by pressing `F7` whenever the cursor is in `tf1`.

The list would return rows in descending order for `col0` column provided that  `cb1` is checked, otherwise would be in ascending order.

*P.S. `KEY-LISTVAL` is the default trigger to invoke a LOV, and fired through `Ctrl+L` key combination. I prefer disabling this default behaviour by adding `KEY-LISTVAL` trigger for `tf1` with a code `null;` in it in order to invoke the LOV from pressing the single key `F7` only.*

Comment: Why KEY-CLRBLK?  Seems to me like KEY-LISTVAL on the text field ("tf1" in your example) would be the better option.

Comment: yes, might be, but I would prefer pressing on a single key(`F7`) rather than combination (`Ctrl+L`) @AndyDan .

Comment: Maybe your key mapping needs to be updated.  For us, key-listval is F9.  And using a key for purpose other than it's intended requires the user to know that, in this particular case, they need to use a different key to get the LOV than they usually do.